# How to get calculated value in hash (attr_accessor) within ActiveRecord query in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have been searching and trying to get this working but i can't find a simple solution.

I have model class called **Task** and this class has a calculated value that i can get through attr_accessor called **overall_rating**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :overall_rating

  def overall_rating
    #returns calculated value
  end
end
```

If i create an instance of ActiveRecord  query like

```
t = Task.first
```

I can get the "overall_rating" value like this

```
t.overall_rating #returns calculated value
```

But there's a way to get the same value but accessing the object as a Hash?

```
t['id'] # returns ID
t['overall_rating'] #returns nil
```

Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: Do you want to do this to call attributes/methods dynamically ?

Comment: Yes, i want it to appear when i create the ActiveRecord instance, but i don't want it to save it on the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply define a method that returns the record as a hash. It uses the **[`attributes` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes) from ActiveRecord** and manually adds the calculated attribute to the hash:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :overall_rating

  def overall_rating
    # returns calculated value, the following is a simple example of a calculation
    id + 100
  end

  def to_h
    attributes.merge("overall_rating" => overall_rating)
  end
end
```

Also note that I changed `attr_accessor` to `attr_reader` as you probably don't want to have a setter defined for the calculated value.

Example:

```
t = Task.find(5)
t.to_h
# => { "id" => 5, "overall_rating" => 105 }
```

Comment: I think this one it's the cleaner way that i can think of too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

simply remove `attr_accessor :overall_rating`

and do the following

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { select("*, [calculated_field] as overall_rating") }
end
```

replace `[calculated_field]` with the calculation you want

Answer (score 0):

IF `overall_rating` is a column in the `tasks` table, you can do something like this:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :set_overall_rating

  def set_overall_rating
    value = #does calculations

    self.overall_rating = value
  end
end
```

Comment: It's a calculated value

Comment: Then you have to convert the record into a hash and then insert the calculated value in the hash

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't move your calculation to SQL and you have to calculate your `overall_rating` in Ruby then you can override the `[]` method. As it calls `read_attribute` I'd suggest to override this method.

Quick and dirty solution:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  def read_attribute(attr_name, &block)
    if attr_name.to_s == "overall_rating"
      overall_rating
    else
      super(attr_name, &block)
    end
  end
end
```